# Ler conteúdo de um PDF em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Tenho um PDF que carrego via input e preciso pegar o conteúdo do arquivo via JavaScript sem o uso de node.js "server side". Consegui pegar o conteúdo em base64, mas não é legível.

Comment: adicione pf o código que é usado para ler o conteúdo do arquivo,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

base64 é um encoding. Vc deve usar o método `atob()` para converter de base64.

Caso tenha mais curiosidade sobre o assunto, há bastante documentação em inglês, como esta https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

---

PS: Como bem indicado nesta resposta do SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/1256062) ainda assim vc não deve obter o resultado esperado, pois imagino que o "base64" que vc tem é o binário do arquivo e não o seu conteúdo.

Sendo assim, seria necessário usar alguma lib externa, como [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). Não conheço a lib e acredito que mesmo com ela não deve funcionar sempre, pois deve ser necessário que o PDF esteja "como texto". Em muitos casos isso não é verdade e seria então necessário uma ferramenta de OCR para interpretar a "imagem" do PDF como texto.

Comment: eu cheguei a ver essa lib mas o problema é que ela é em node e eu queria algo em client side mas acho que isso não sera possível

Comment: Creio que funcione, sim, no browser: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples

Comment: Verifiquei que vc repetiu a pergunta e que inclusive usou o PDF.js. Pelo menos ficou então resolvido.