# ler conteudo de um pdf utilizando javascript client side

Tags: javascript, pdf

Tenho um PDF que carrego via input e preciso pegar o conteúdo do arquivo via JavaScript sem o uso de node.js "server side". Consegui pegar o conteúdo em base64, mas não é legível.

Código que estou usando:

```html
<input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertToBase64() {
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("inputFile").files;
        if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
            var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var base64;
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            };
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
            console.log(fileReader);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ler conteúdo de um PDF em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/431700/ler-conte%c3%bado-de-um-pdf-em-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso do lado do cliente utilizando esta biblioteca

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/

Eu fiz um exemplo tomando como base este tutorial

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript

Eu instalei os dois arquivos da biblioteca na mesma pasta que o HTML e fiz a leitura do PDF selecionado no input file. O resultado aparece no console do navegador, ele cria um array, onde cada item é o texto de uma página

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="pdf.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>PDF.js</h1>
  
  <input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />
  <script>
   pdfjsLib.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';
    function convertToBase64() {
    var selectedFile = document.getElementById("inputFile").files;
    if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
     var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
     var fileReader = new FileReader();
     var base64;
     fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
      base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
      lerPDF(base64);
     };
     fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
   }
   
   function lerPDF(fileToLoad) {
     pdfjsLib.getDocument(fileToLoad).then(function (pdf) {
     var pdfDocument = pdf;
     var pagesPromises = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < pdf.numPages; i++) {
      // Required to prevent that i is always the total of pages
      (function (pageNumber) {
       pagesPromises.push(getPageText(pageNumber, pdfDocument));
      })(i + 1);
     }

     Promise.all(pagesPromises).then(function (pagesText) {

      // Display text of all the pages in the console
      console.log(pagesText);
     });

    }, function (reason) {
     // PDF loading error
     console.error(reason);
    });

     
    
   } 

   /**
    * Retrieves the text of a specif page within a PDF Document obtained through pdf.js 
    * 
    * @param {Integer} pageNum Specifies the number of the page 
    * @param {PDFDocument} PDFDocumentInstance The PDF document obtained 
    **/
   function getPageText(pageNum, PDFDocumentInstance) {
    // Return a Promise that is solved once the text of the page is retrieven
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     PDFDocumentInstance.getPage(pageNum).then(function (pdfPage) {
      // The main trick to obtain the text of the PDF page, use the getTextContent method
      pdfPage.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
       var textItems = textContent.items;
       var finalString = "";

       // Concatenate the string of the item to the final string
       for (var i = 0; i < textItems.length; i++) {
        var item = textItems[i];

        finalString += item.str + " ";
       }

       // Solve promise with the text retrieven from the page
       resolve(finalString);
      });
     });
    });
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: deu certo obrigado!!